# Disallow some numbers in form input field in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In the form input field I want to display numbers like scroll option but I want to disable some numbers, which I get from the database.

For example, if my database query returns 3,5 and 7, the user should not be able to input those numbers in the form input field.

```
<form>
<input name="sid" type="number">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(function(){  
    var preventNumbers = [3,4,5] //array of numbers
    $('input[name="sid"]').keydown(function(e){
        if(preventNumbers.indexOf(parseInt(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) > -1){
        return false;
    }
  });
})
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0ot1m8rt/)

Here I have created array of numbers which you want to prevent from type in input, and with keydown function you can prevent it.

If you want to prevent arrow event also then you have to catch the `mouseup` event like:

```
$(function(){  
    var preventNumbers = [3,4,5]
    $('input[name="sid"]').keydown(function(e){
        if(preventNumbers.indexOf(parseInt(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) > -1)         {
        return false;
    }
  }).mouseup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
    if(preventNumbers.indexOf(parseInt(val)) > -1)          {
        $(this).val('');
    }
  })
})
```

## [Updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0ot1m8rt/2/)

Comment: thanks for your answer bro but still I am able to input 3, 4 and 5 using up and down buttons in the input field

Comment: So do you want to prevent that also?

Comment: Can you use input type="text" instead of number?

Comment: If that's the only way I will change it

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using jQuery, you can bind to the keyup event, and check the key that was pressed, then return false if it's one that you don't want the user to select:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```